# Create bash file using python

Tags: python, linux, bash

This is parameter that i want to run:

```
cd ../linux-3.11/; cp arch/x86/configs/byt_32_tz_emgd_defconfig .config; make ARCH=i386 oldconfig; make ARCH=i386 -j 4
```

I want this to save to bash file using python.
I want it run exactly as user input into linux command (without semicolon) because of path issue.

Please provide me some simple example how create bash file and run it in python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to save it to a file, just run it in a subprocess:

```
import os
os.system("""cd ../linux-3.11/; cp arch/x86/configs/byt_32_tz_emgd_defconfig .config; make ARCH=i386 oldconfig; make ARCH=i386 -j 4""")
```

You can use `subprocess` if you want to do input/output into the subprocess. One trick I really like is making your script `script.ipy` with a shebang of `#!/usr/bin/ipython`. Then you can use `!` to run bash commands. I haven't seen many other people do this but it's awefully convenient.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, but it not exactly what I want, can you provide me how to create and run bash file using python? its because I using variable parameters.

Comment: @azmilhafiz `os.system` just takes a string, you can put anything you want in the string.